# PHP API For FusionCharts' PowerCharts

Tags: php, api, fusioncharts

I am interested in using charts from the FusionCharts PowerCharts library (demo's available at fusioncharts.com).

There is a decent PHP library for building out the standard FusionCharts, however looking through the class it doesn't currently support the PowerCharts library.  Is anyone aware of a library that works with the PowerCharts version of the library?

Comment: Nothing to do with your question :) but have you also checked out Highcharts? Depends what type of charts you want to do I see powerCharts does network diagrams, Highcharts does bar/line etc etc - jQuery-based and very nice, easy to use with PHP.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what you are trying to achieve that is missing? Ideally, it is possible to execute all API at the JavaScript level. Also, the Highcharts version enhanced by FusionCharts has network diagrams and many other charts from the PowerCharts suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fusion charts (and PowerCharts) is relatively easy to use.  You just throw an XML or JSON string at it and it does the work.  For example, here's the XML that powers the "drag column" demo on the PowerCharts website:

[http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/visually-editable-charts/](http://www.fusioncharts.com/Demos/DragColumn/Data.xml)

There are several different methods to get data over to FusionCharts, but I've found in working with them that some are better documented and supported than others.  I've not had much success using their Javascript-based charts (which are powered by Highcharts, which as @Brian mentioned are AMAZING) but that could have been because they were brand new when I deployed HighCharts into my application.  I didn't have the choice when doing my project as the company had bought a license to Fusion before I started working here and wasn't interested in paying for another solution.

One final caveat:  the company that makes HighCharts is India-based.  Be aware that sometimes the documentation and support forums use some unconventionally-structure English.  Also, employees from the company frequently answer support Forum questions with the response "See the documentation" which is amazingly frustrating when you get stuck.